# How do I initialize a listener in a recycler adapter?

Tags: java, android, listener

I need to be able to send the position of the tapped recycler item to the parent fragment by means of a listener but everytime I tap it, it says that the listener is null.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.eataway.partner.adapters.MenuAdapter$SectionAdapterListener.onSectionSend(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.rest.partner.adapters.MenuAdapter.lambda$onBindViewHolder$0$MenuAdapter(MenuAdapter.java:82)
        at com.rest.partner.adapters.-$$Lambda$MenuAdapter$TzEQ_dT_4Yb5iXO0LwjA0DjCNEI.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
```

Here is the relevant adapter code. At the top is the constructor class followed by the listener definition and setting.
Then in the onBindViewHolder I trigger the click action for the item i.e. the entire view for that item is clickable. And at the bottom is the inner class for the relevant viewHolder.

```
// Constructor class
    public MenuAdapter(Context adapterContext, ArrayList<DishItem> restaurantDishItemArrayList) {
        this.adapterContext = adapterContext;
        this.restaurantDishItemArrayList = restaurantDishItemArrayList;
    }

    // Define listener to send chosen section
    public interface SectionAdapterListener {
        void onSectionSend(int position);
    }

    // Set the listener. Must be called from the fragment
    public void setSectionAdapterListener(SectionAdapterListener sectionAdapterListener) {
        this.sectionAdapterListener = sectionAdapterListener;
    }

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (adapterContext instanceof SectionAdapterListener) sectionAdapterListener = (SectionAdapterListener) adapterContext;
        if (holder instanceof SectionViewHolder) {
            ((SectionViewHolder)holder).tvHeaderName.setText(restaurantDishItemArrayList.get(position).getHeaderName());
            if (sectionAdapterListener == null ) Log.d(TAG, "listener is null");
            ((SectionViewHolder)holder).viewForeground.setOnClickListener(v -> sectionAdapterListener.onSectionSend(position));

        } else if (holder instanceof DishViewHolder) {
            ((DishViewHolder)holder).tvMenuItemName.setText(restaurantDishItemArrayList.get(position).getMenuItemName());
            ((DishViewHolder)holder).tvMenuItemDescription.setText(restaurantDishItemArrayList.get(position).getMenuItemDescription());
            }
    }

public class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tvHeaderName;
        private RelativeLayout viewForeground;

        public SectionViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvHeaderName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_header_name);
            viewForeground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.foreground_view);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/61290283/12386821

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface class. Then add the interface to your RecyclerAdapter constructor.

```
 YourInterface listener;

 public MenuAdapter(YourInterface listener, Context adapterContext, ArrayList<DishItem> restaurantDishItemArrayList) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.adapterContext = adapterContext;
        this.restaurantDishItemArrayList = restaurantDishItemArrayList;
    }
```

Then on your activity

```
MenuAdapter menuAdapter = new MenuAdapter(listener, context, arraylist);
```

Comment: I am relatively new to java. How would I create an interface class? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check that https://developer.android.com/studio/write/create-java-class

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `NullPointerException` check if the listener is null before using its method, so change `onBindViewHolder()` to return if the `sectionAdapterListener`  is `null`

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (adapterContext instanceof SectionAdapterListener) sectionAdapterListener = (SectionAdapterListener) adapterContext;
        if (holder instanceof SectionViewHolder) {
            ((SectionViewHolder)holder).tvHeaderName.setText(restaurantDishItemArrayList.get(position).getHeaderName());
            if (sectionAdapterListener == null ) {
                Log.d(TAG, "listener is null");
                return;
            }
            ((SectionViewHolder)holder).viewForeground.setOnClickListener(v -> sectionAdapterListener.onSectionSend(position));

        } else if (holder instanceof DishViewHolder) {
            ((DishViewHolder)holder).tvMenuItemName.setText(restaurantDishItemArrayList.get(position).getMenuItemName());
            ((DishViewHolder)holder).tvMenuItemDescription.setText(restaurantDishItemArrayList.get(position).getMenuItemDescription());
        }
    }
```

Otherwise you need to call `setSectionAdapterListener()` from the activity/fragment that creates this adapter

Comment: I tried this and while the app does not crash, I am not able to use the onClick method for the view type.

Answer (score 0):

You can add below code into onBindViewHolder method of your adapter class..

```
holder.itemView.setonClickListener{
 //add your code here....
}
```